# Audio hangs on repeated playback

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

How do I fix hanging audio in Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)?

When I playback audio using, for example, aplay, the first playback
works fine.  Subsequent playback will hang indefinitely.  Several
ctrl+c signals will restore playback for one additional play.

Reproduction steps:

(1) Download any wav:
`wget http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/wav/oboe-bassoon.wav`

(2) Use aplay to playback the sound.  First play works fine, sounds good:

```
$ aplay oboe-bassoon.wav
Playing WAVE 'oboe-bassoon.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate
48000 Hz, Stereo
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
aplay: pcm_write:1939: write error: Interrupted system call
```

Second play hangs without any playback

```
$ aplay oboe-bassoon.wav
Playing WAVE 'oboe-bassoon.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate
48000 Hz, Stereo
```

I have tried loading PulseAudio daemon in verbose mode to see what
might be going on.  When the process hangs, I see:

```
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] source.c: Processing rewind...
```

I also see a lot of these warnings:

```
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] protocol-native.c: Implicit underrun of
'ALSA Playback'
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: Found underrun 22784 bytes ago
(1792 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
```

Any ideas how to fix these hangs?